# Why Does Next Line Execute Before Function Returns a Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var newID = saveNewGame(newName, newShortName, "1");  
alert (newID + " Here");

function saveNewGame(newName, newShortName, myNumber) {
    myRequest.open("POST", "savegame.php", false);
    if (myRequest.status === 200) {
            var myNewID = myRequest.responseText;
            alert(myNewID + " There");
            return myNewID;
}
```

When ran, I get a popup message: 'undefined Here' followed by a popup message: '5 There'.  - More complex code added.  The function performs an XMLHttpRequest (myRequest) - but set to Async = false.

I'd think that '5 There' should popup first and 'undefined Here' should say '5 Here' and popup second.  Why does this do what it does?

NOTE: I snipped out the XML setup stuff

Comment: It works exactly as it should -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yv7843c4/1/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code as you show it (with a definition for `newName` and `newShortName` in your answer in a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/a5da81kp/, it does not do what you said it does.  In fact, it shows the two alerts with legitimate strings just like one would expect.

It shows:

```
5 There
5 Here
```

So, it seems likely that your real code is not as simple as the code you have in your question.  I'd guess that you perhaps have some asynchronous code somewhere that does indeed change the order of execution.  But the hypothesis in your question is simply not correct.  That code works as one would expect.

Comment: Added more code - asynchornous must be the key, but it's set to FALSE in the .open call